# Connecting flight from Muscat - Turkish Airlines

Tags: air-travel

I have below travel plan from Hyd(India) Amsterdam

*Hyderabad to Muscat - Oman Air

4 hrs wait in Muscat Int. Airport

*Muscat to Istanbul - Turkish Airlines

2 hrs wait in Istanbul Airport

*Istanbul to Amsterdam - Turkish Airlines

I have no plans to carry any check in luggage and Oman Airlines and Turkish Airlines is not code shared though I have single ticket.

Questions :

1. Is 4 hrs waiting enough in Muscat?
2. Do I need to go through Immigration ?
3. Can I do online check -in 24 hrs prior for all the flights?
4. Can I directly go to International Transfer ?